# Atualizar metodo de component filho VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tentando atualizar um metodo de um component filho, mas até agora não tive solução, minha questão é a seguinte.

Dentro do `Header.vue`, eu exibo as horas pendentes

```
<span>
    <b>{{Hours}}</b> horas pendentes
</span>

    hours(){                
  axios.get(`http://localhost:83/Pendencia/HorasPendentes/${this.$localStorage.get('RecursoId')}`)
    .then(res => {
    this.Hours = res.data.Retorno
  })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Agora no meu arquivo `Pendencia.vue`, eu acho uma `API`, e no retorno dessa `API` chamada no `Pendencia.vue` gostaria de chamar novamente a `API` do `Header.vue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `$children` para encontrar um componente filho e assim acessar todos os seus `data`, `methods`, etc..

Tente criar da seguinte forma:

```
const componenteFilho = this.$children.find(component => component.$options.name === "Nome_do_componente_filho");

componenteFilho.funcao_da_Api()
```

Então use isso em um `method` , `mounted` ou de alguma forma melhor para você ;)

Comment: Eu consigo usar isso mesmo na minha questão (que talvez eu não tenho explicado direito). Eu uso `Nested Routes`, ai o `Pendencias` faz parte do `Dashboard`, e o `Header`, está sendo chamado no `Dashboard` e não no `Pendencia`, desculpe não ter explicado isso antes.

Comment: Não consegue encontrar o componente Header a partir do Pendencias é isso?

Comment: Sim, eu usei o seu codigo, dando um `console.log(this.$children.find(component => component.$options.name === "Header"))` e me retornou `undefined`

Comment: entendi, então os dois componentes são filhos do `Dashboard`.

No caso vc pode voltar pro pai e procurar o componente filho: 
 `this.$parent.$children.find(component => component.$options.name === "Header")`

Comment: Funcionou, valeu

Comment: @RubensBarbosa Seguindo a mesma logica, como eu faria o mesmo, porem para chamar uma função que está dentro do meu component filho? <Datepicker /> ?